# How to fix CMake Error: The Source directory

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am trying to compile simple c++ file  by using CMake but getting following error:
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/john/Desktop/example" does not appear to contain CMakelists.txt

```
john@john:~/ Desktop/sample$ ls
CMakelists.txt hello.cpp
john@john:~/ Desktop/sample$ cmake .
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/john/Desktop/example" does not appear to contain CMakelists.txt
```

i've already checked other posts about that, but none of them help me to solve it

Comment: Apparently you have "example" where you need "sample".

Comment: What is the content of the `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: Also normally in `CMake` you build in a different folder from the source. It's not necessary but it will help you when your projects get more complicated. This explains some reasons: https://cgold.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/out-of-source.html

Comment: @johnny folder called actually sample. This is not the Problem

Comment: @drescherjm the content of CMakelists.txt is also correct

Comment: Why cmake not see .txt file?

Comment: The file name must be __`CMakeLists.txt`__. The error message actually shows you the correct name, your shown output seems to not be copy-pasted but manually typed, reproducing the same problem. When asking a question on SO, please copy and paste the __exact__ output you get.

Comment: I see you have a "CMakelists.txt". That's *not* the same as what CMake is looking for, which is "CMakeLists.txt". Note the capital "L". Case matters (and not just here, for file names, but for variable names and much more as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JesperJuhl pointed out, the problem was Capitalization. Thanks all for your contribution.

```
suppose to be CMakeLists.txt not CMakelists.txt
```

I am really sorry for kind of unnecessary question. But im gonna be more carefully by next time